# Responsive rectangle with responsively rounded corners

Tags: html, css

I have a working example of a responsive square with rounded corners that scale with the viewport.  Please see the snippet below and ignore some of the other transformations I made in the `.diamond` class selector:

**HTML**

```
<div class="diamond"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.diamond {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #7FDBFF;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ff52bf, #9a52ff);
  transform: rotate(315deg);
  border-radius: 8%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -375px;
  top: -400px;
}

.diamond:after {
  content:"";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

Now I tried to apply similar logic to a rectangle, however, the rounded corners taper at a different angle on the sides vs the top and bottom as opposed to an even taper on each vertex.  Here's what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="rectangle"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rectangle{
    width: 75%;
    background: #F9FAFE;
    border-radius: 8%;
}
.rectangle:after{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
}
```

Here is the code rendered on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bzVjZZ) so you can see what I mean.

Any recommendations on how to achieve more rounded corners that will also be responsive similar to the square example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `%` as the unit for the rounding. However, unless your viewport is a square, 1% of the height will not be the same as 1% of the width, causing your corners (or anything else in CSS) not to be uniform. You can easily fix this by using a fixed unit, such as `px`.

However, since you still want the `border-radius` to change with the size of the viewport, you can use either `vh` (viewport-height) or `vw` (viewport-width) as the units for border-radius. These will act similarly to the `%` unit except that you can specify whether you are using the height or the width of the viewport as the reference.

For example, the following CSS should work:

```
.rectangle{
  width: 75%;
  background: #F9FAFE;
  border-radius: 8vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned, percentages change for each axis so that won't work for your situation. Although viewport height (vh) and width (vw) can work better, you may want to look at using rem units, which are based on the font size of the html element. This won't change as the window is resized, and you can easily make it zoom/responsive by setting your base font size using viewport width (vw) units.

Comment: thank you for your response.  i didn't even consider that `rem` units would work in this situation.  good to know though.  i'll play around with both.